ng build gerando pasta 'browser' -> dist/***/browser/index.html
Ao executar o comando ````ng build``` está gerando uma pasta 'browser' dentro da pasta do projeto.
Atualizei a versão do angular no projeto e isso começou a acontecer.
pasta gerada
Versao do Angular
angular.json
{
  "$schema": "./node_modules/@angular/cli/lib/config/schema.json",
  "version": 1,
  "newProjectRoot": "projects",
  "projects": {
    "redmine-check": {
      "projectType": "application",
      "schematics": {},
      "root": "",
      "sourceRoot": "src",
      "prefix": "app",
      "architect": {
        "build": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:application",
          "options": {
            "outputPath": "dist/redmine-check",
            "index": "src/index.html",
            "browser": "src/main.ts",
            "allowedCommonJsDependencies": [
              "papaparse"
           ],
            "polyfills": [
              "zone.js"
            ],
            "tsConfig": "tsconfig.app.json",
            "assets": [
              "src/favicon.ico",
              "src/assets"
            ],
            "styles": [
              "@angular/material/prebuilt-themes/indigo-pink.css",
              "src/styles.css"
            ],
            "scripts": [],
            "server": "src/main.server.ts",
            "prerender": false,
            "ssr": false
            /*
            * Evitar erro :ERROR ReferenceError: localStorage is not defined
            */ 
            // "prerender": true,
            // "ssr": {
            //   "entry": "server.ts"
            // }
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "budgets": [
                {
                  "type": "initial",
                  "maximumWarning": "1mb",
                  "maximumError": "1mb"
                },
                {
                  "type": "anyComponentStyle",
                  "maximumWarning": "2kb",
                  "maximumError": "4kb"
                }
              ],
              "outputHashing": "all"
            },
            "development": {
              "optimization": false,
              "extractLicenses": false,
              "sourceMap": true
            }
          },
          "defaultConfiguration": "production"
        },
        "serve": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:dev-server",
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "buildTarget": "redmine-check:build:production"
            },
            "development": {
              "buildTarget": "redmine-check:build:development"
            }
          },
          "defaultConfiguration": "development"
        },
        "extract-i18n": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:extract-i18n",
          "options": {
            "buildTarget": "redmine-check:build"
          }
        },
        "test": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:karma",
          "options": {
            "polyfills": [
              "zone.js",
              "zone.js/testing"
            ],
            "tsConfig": "tsconfig.spec.json",
            "assets": [
              "src/favicon.ico",
              "src/assets"
            ],
            "styles": [
              "@angular/material/prebuilt-themes/indigo-pink.css",
              "src/styles.css"
            ],
            "scripts": []
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "cli": {
    "analytics": "fbded91a-56a5-4cd3-bf40-157b14de1773"
  }
}


package.json
{
  "name": "redmine-check",
  "version": "3.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve --proxy-config proxy.conf.json",
    "build": "ng build --base-href /redmine-check/ --configuration production",
    "watch": "ng build --watch --configuration development",
    "test": "ng test",
    "serve:ssr:redmine-check": "node dist/redmine-check/server/server.mjs"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^17.3.0",
    "@angular/cdk": "^17.3.2",
    "@angular/common": "^17.3.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "^17.3.0",
    "@angular/core": "^17.3.0",
    "@angular/forms": "^17.3.0",
    "@angular/material": "^17.3.2",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^17.3.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^17.3.0",
    "@angular/platform-server": "^17.3.0",
    "@angular/router": "^17.3.0",
    "@angular/ssr": "^17.3.2",
    "bootstrap": "^5.3.3",
    "express": "^4.18.2",
    "papaparse": "^5.4.1",
    "rxjs": "~7.8.0",
    "tslib": "^2.3.0",
    "zone.js": "~0.14.3"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "^17.3.2",
    "@angular/cli": "^17.3.2",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^17.3.0",
    "@types/express": "^4.17.17",
    "@types/jasmine": "~5.1.0",
    "@types/node": "^18.18.0",
    "@types/papaparse": "^5.3.14",
    "jasmine-core": "~5.1.0",
    "karma": "~6.4.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~3.2.0",
    "karma-coverage": "~2.2.0",
    "karma-jasmine": "~5.1.0",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "~2.1.0",
    "typescript": "~5.4.2"
  }
}




No arquivo angular.json você deve procurar por "outputPath" que fica nas configurações de  build e passar a seguinte configuração:
"outputPath": {
              "base": "dist/frontend",
              "browser": ""
            },

No exemplo acima ao rodar npm run build --prod, o site estará na pasta dist/frontend e não mais criará a pasta browser.

Nas versões Angular 17 e superiores, o caminho de saída padrão do comando ng build foi modificado para incluir um browser subdiretório dentro da pasta  dist. Esta mudança visa melhorar a organização da compilação e agilizar as configurações de renderização do lado do servidor (SSR).
Restaurando o comportamento anterior:
Altere as configurações em seu angular.json para atingir o caminho de saída pré-Angular 17 (apenas dist/):
Atualizar outputPath:
Defina a propriedade browser como uma string vazia (""). Isso desativa efetivamente a criação do subdiretório browser.
Exemplo:
"outputPath": {
  "base": "dist/",
  "browser": ""  // Set to an empty string
}

O "outputPath" não pode ser alterado dessa forma se o  "ssr" estiver habilitado. Então precisa desabilitar o "ssr".

Como está escrito atualmente, sua resposta não é clara. Por favor, pode [edit] para adicionar mais detalhes, que ajudarão outras pessoas a entender como isso resolve a pergunta feita. Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre como escrever boas respostas na Central de Ajuda.

Para resolver o problema da pasta adicional "browser" após compilar, basta trocar a configuração no arquivo angular.json em versões do Angular 17+ standalone.
Modificando o arquivo:

angular.json

De:

"outputPath": "dist/redmine-check",

Para:

"outputPath": {
  "base": "dist/redmine-check",
  "browser": ""
},

Agora quando executar o ng build, sem informar a opção --browser no próprio comando, irá exportar na pasta sem adicionar uma pasta a mais chamada "browser".
A documentação oficial do build:
https://angular.dev/cli/build
